# selecting specific element from a nested array using php foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

let say I have this nested array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => page
    [1] => section
    [2] => side
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => url1
                    [1] => url2
                    [2] => url3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => url4
                    [1] => url5
                    [2] => url6
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => url7
                    [1] => url8
                    [2] => url9
                )

        )

)
```

I want to foreach (php) to get from each array element with index[1]

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        echo $key." : ".$value."\n";

foreach($value as $key => $value){
    echo "   ". $key." : ".$value."\n";

    foreach($value as $key => $value){
        echo "     ". $key." : ".$value."\n";
    }
}
}
```

and this is my output:

```
0 : page
1 : section
2 : side
3 : Array
   0 : Array
     0 : url1
     1 : url2
     2 : url3
   1 : Array
     0 : url4
     1 : url5
     2 : url6
   2 : Array
     0 : url7
     1 : url8
     2 : url9
```

but I want to select specific element from each array at the same time some thing like this:

```
 1 : url2
 1 : url5
 1 : url8
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the entries in a separate array and iterate over it afterwards. Based on your code, like so:

```
<?php
$entriesWithOne = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    echo $key." : ".$value."\n";

    foreach($value as $key => $value){
        echo "   ". $key." : ".$value."\n";

        foreach($value as $key => $value){
            echo "     ". $key." : ".$value."\n";
            if ($key == 1) {
                $entriesWithOne[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach($entriesWithOne as $url) {
    echo '1 : ' . $url . "\n";
}
```

Please note, that I only made the check (and adding to the array) within the inner-most loop in this example, as it fulfills your requirement. However, if you like to collect from the other loops too, you would have to do something similar there.